# Mutual Information on a shared pdf

Tags: information-theory

Let $y = x_1 + x_2$ and assume that $x_1$ and $x_2$ are i.i.d. RV both with the probability densitiy function ${pdf}_{x_1}(x) = pdf_{x_2}(x) = f(x)$. What is the mutual information $I(y|x_1)$ maximizing pdf $f(x)$ and how to proof this?

Comment: Your question is not clear: what is the thing you want to maximize, which is the variable, and what are the restrictions ?

Comment: I want to maximize the mutual information with respect to the pdf $f(x)$

Comment: What did you try? Where are you stuck? Hint - one way to make $I(X_1;Y)$ big is to make $H(X_1)$ big, and to make $H(X_1|Y)$ small - i.e., lots can be inferred about $X_1$ from $Y$. Can you think of a setting where this happens?

Comment: Yes, this is a problem in communication eng. Iam stuck in finding the pdf $f(x)$ that maximizes the mutial information of this setup.

Comment: @stochasticboy321 do you have any idea?

Comment: I have the same question - what did you try? Did the hint I gave make sense? Did you think about that? Did you try something else?

Comment: I calcualted $pdf_y(x) =  pdf_{x_1} * pdf_{x_2}$ and the conditional $pdf_{y| x_1}(y| x_1) = (pdf_{x_2})(y-x_1)$ and the joint pdf of $y$ and $x1$ as $pdf_{y,x1} = pdf_{y| x_1}(y| x_1) pdf_{x_1}(x_1)$. Finally the mutual information is $I(y;x_s) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} pdf_{y, x_1}(y, x_1) log_2\left(\frac{pdf_{y, x_1}(y, x_1)}{pdf_y(y) pdf_{x_1}(x_1)}\right)\,dx_1  \,dy$. I know that you can simiplify this expression but to make just H(x1) large is not the way to go, because H(x1|y) will increase aswell...

Comment: Okay - working in the discrete case, consider $X_1$ supported on $\{1, 10, 10^2\}$. Can you give a simple bound for $H(X_1|Y)$? What about when $X_1$ is supported on $\{1,10,10^2,10^3\}?$ Generalise this for the discrete case.

Comment: No, can you please present the hint, how to state the simple bound?

Comment: In the first case, suppose I tell you that $Y = 110$. What are the possibile values of $X_1$? More generally, suppose $X_1$ is supported on $\{10^k : k \in \mathbb{N}\},$ and $Y$ takes the value $10^j + 10^k$ ($j$ and $k$ may be equal). What are the possibile values of $X_1$? Does this yield a bound on $H(X_1|Y)$?